# Cognos Planning 10 -- Setting up user security

Tags: cognos

I am editing user security and am trying to give a user access to an e.List item. I select the user using the [...] button and successfully find that user by searching in our AD domain.

After I select the user and press OK, that user does not come into the CAC, just this error The filter will only accept groups and roles. Users will not be added to the filter. I don't see any filters here at all.

Have you seen this before and is it possible to set up security by users?

Thank you,
WE
[image: PC LOAD LETTER?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from ericlfg on http://www.cognoise.com/community/index.php/board,15.0.html:

Hi William,

The message you are receiving is by design.  In order to add a specific user, rather than a group or role, that use needs to be a member of some kind of hierarchy in your security provider.

Ex: If you're using cognos groups and roles with a Role called "Test".  You would populate this test role with members from your namespace.  In the CAC, you would then select the Test group when you click on the elipsis and then that will allow you to select your individual user (or alternatively the Test role).

The same would be true if you're trying to add members directly from your 3rd party authentication provider.  The individual users need to be part of a roll-up role or group in order to add that roll-up role or group to the filter.  Once added to the filter you can select the individual users.

Hope this helps.